# How can i custom sort dictionary by value base near zero via c#

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary<int, double>` and i want to custom sort it. But is it a little different sorting.

For example here is the codes:

```
Dictionary<int, double> dicZeroPeriods = new Dictionary<int, double>();
dicZeroPeriods.Add (80,-3.5);
dicZeroPeriods.Add (90,-2.4);
dicZeroPeriods.Add (50,4.2);
dicZeroPeriods.Add (65,1.2);
```

So how can i custom sort the `dicZeroPeriods` by value base near zero. I mean the result should be:

```
65,1.2
90,-2.4
80,-3.5
50,4.2
```

Comment: `Dictionary` don't have a sort method you may need to use `SortedDictionary` check this post [How to use custom IComparer for SortedDictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720009/how-to-use-custom-icomparer-for-sorteddictionary), or recreate the dictionary in sorted order

Comment: I can't use SortedDictionary because i have some same entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `OrderBy` with [`Math.Abs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4ke8e73(v=vs.110).aspx) function. Here you go:

```
dicZeroPeriods = dicZeroPeriods.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(x.Value))
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is working clearly. And how can i do that without LINQ?

Comment: @lotomax I can say how. With a lot of pain. Write loop manually and realize one of sorting algorithm.

Comment: Thank you, i need that because i wanna use this in JAVA. And there is no LINQ sorting in java.

Answer (score 0):

use `Math.Abs()` to sort your dictionary elements by its absolute values. Math.Abs(1.2) < Math.Abs(-3.5) and so on.